# How to use hook_menu to create wildcard aliases to a normal node page

Tags: 7, redirection, routes

I have a node template where I check the url for the existance of some parts and play with that, eg, if the node is called `your/recipies`, I catch urls like

```
/your/recepies/bananas
/your/recepies/apples
/your/recepies/oranges
```

and check the url for bananes,apples,oranges in the template.

I used aliases to point those urls to the original node, but they keep on dissapearing. It's probably be a breeze to set up a module router, like

```
function kitchen_menu() {
        $items = array();

        $items['your/recipies/%'] = array(
            'title'  => t('Recipies'),
            'page callback' => 'drupal_magic',
            'page arguments' => array('your/recipies')

        );
 }
```

to make drupal just render the node (and not redirect somewhere). 
however, i cant find out what to write instead of `drupal_magic`.

(recipies, if you must know, is a webform; not something i can easily generate myself)

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I now did this different. I won't accept this as an answer, because it isnt. But this works as well in my case

```
function kitchen_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
    if (preg_match('|^your/recepies(/\w+)?|', $path, $matches)) {
        $path = 'your/recepies';
    }
}
```